# What is the easiest way to add rendered content to the JSON response in Django-REST-Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm just starting out with DRF and it seems I'm a bit lost in documentation looking for something very simple: for some of my models, I want to return their HTML rendering as a snippet in a field. As an example, I need something like this (`text` is a "normal" field, while `html` is a rendering of this object using some previously defined template):

`{
   "id": 1,
   "text": "This is a heading",
   "html": "<h1>This is a heading</h1>"
}`

I could certainly write custom views for that, but I'm pretty sure there is something like a standard and easy way to do this. But which is it?

Comment: Are you using a serializer or not? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield).

Example serializer could be:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    html = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_text_html')

    def get_text_html(self, obj):
        return make_html(obj.text)

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'html')
```

Another approach would be defining a [custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#custom-fields). I did this for a field that was markdown in the database and returned a HTML representation to the user.